# MDX; Get aggregation of measure over all values in a hiercharchy except named ones

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, mdx

This tuple gets me an aggregation of measure X in the dimension of `[MyHierarchy].[MyHierarchy].&[some_value]`.

```
([Measures].[X], [MyHierarchy].[MyHierarchy].&[some_value])
```

But what is the complement - ie  Measures.X in the same hierarchy **but excluding** `[MyHierarchy].[MyHierarchy].&[some_value]`

I'm sure it's the EXCEPT function but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea to aggregate over any kind of set is something like:

```
with member [Measures].[Y] as 
       aggregate( 
         except( [hierarchy].members, { excluded } ), 
         [Measures].[X] )
       )
```

Aggregate() is handling whatever actual aggregation of the [Measures]. The issue is that if [hierarchy].members contains some intermediate (parent) members, you'll have values counted twice.

If the aggregation is SUM and you've an *all* member, then the following is giving the expected result :

```
with member [Measures].[Y] as 
       ( [hierarchy].[all], [Measures].[X] ) 
       - sum( { excluded }, [Measures].[X] )
```

If no *all* then you can use members of the first level:

```
with member [Measures].[Y] as 
       sum( [hierarchy].levels(0), [Measures].[X] ) 
       - sum( { excluded }, [Measures].[X] )
```

_

Comment: Nice - So basically do the calc my self as all - not_wanted? Thanks for the detailed explantion. I didn't know about LEVELS(0).

Answer (score 1):

The following expresion works with non linear aggregation functions:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Y] as 
       Aggregate( 
         Except( [MyHierarchy].[MyHierarchy].&[some_value].Level.Members, { [MyHierarchy].[MyHierarchy].&[some_value] } ), 
         [Measures].[X] )
       )
```

You can generalize it when you have to exclude several members that **belong to the same level** (the excluded members are in the `excludedMembers` set):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Y] as 
       Aggregate( 
         Except( excludedMembers.Item(0).Level.Members , excludedMembers ), 
         [Measures].[X] )
       )
```